# Is it possible to synthesize permanganate electrochemically?

Tags: electrochemistry, synthesis, electrolysis, oxidation-state

I have been researching the production of peroxy acids and other strong oxidizers. I was wondering if it's possible to produce permanganic acid if I were to cast an anode containing Manganese Dioxide from a battery?

**Update**

I was able to produce what I would believe to be the permanganate anion based on the color of the solution and the composition of one of the electrodes.

[image]

Comment: See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th); also, [Why can't I ask questions on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-cant-i-ask-questions-on-stackoverflow). It looks like the system temporarily blocked you from posting new question, probably due to heuristics based on the former activity (number of downvotes/flagged posts or comments/improper behavior).

Comment: From what I can see, neither of Chemistry.SE moderators manually suspended you in any way, and we are probably not going to be able to inform you regarding the exact reason for blocking as we don't have access to the blocking algorithms. Also, please note that edits as "*MODERATOR, Why can't I ask new questions?*" are not a good fit for the main Q&A site since they have little to do with the question itself and are better suited for [Meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'll remove the Edits.

Comment: @andselisk, Okay I do tend to keep my questions short, but that's because on the engineering site I was scolded for providing too much detail. If you look at my questions, they are completely legitimate. I asked about some aqueous chlorine, (I know that now), a pink species that I had no Idea was chromium and I has a tough time with some copper oxidation that I asked about. That's all. The chemists can be a bit condescending at times too. I have a very friendly demeanor, but when someone is rude to me, that can illicit an extremely negative response. I was born and raised in New York City.

Comment: @andselisk, Once I'm 100% sure of the step by step process, If I wanted to answer my own question on this occasion, because I did indeed produce some permanganate. It appeared like clockwork. beautiful fuchsia solution. Though as it concentrates, it seems to be looking more like Kiwi-strawberry Mystic. How should I format the answer?

Comment: It's absolutely fine post a lengthy and detailed question. I think I remember that post of yours which is unfortunately deleted now (the system does automatic cleanup based on the score and number of visitors) and I thought it was totally fine (AFAIR there were purple-tinted pictures and a decent description of the experimental setup). The thing is, sometimes even good questions get closed by users for no apparent reason *just because*. This is indeed frustrating. Keep in mind every closed question may be reopened after tweaking/improving. Also, it looks like you can still answer questions.